# Postgres 13.6, my background process, causes high CPU with warning "worker took too long to start; canceled"

Tags: postgresql, go, backgroundworker

I am using PostgreSql & golang in my project
I have created a postgresql background worker using golang. This background worker listens to LISTEN/NOTIFY channel in postgres and writes the data it receives to a file.

The trigger(which supplies data to channel), background worker registration and the background worker's main function are all in one .so file. The core background process logic is in another helper .so file. The background process main loads the helper .so file using dlopen and executes the core logic from it.

**Issue faced:**
It works fine in windows, but in linux where I tried with postgres 13.6, there is a problems.
It runs as intended for a while, but after about 2-3hrs, postgresql postmaster's CPU utilization shoots up and seems to get stuck. The CPU shoot up is very sudden (less than 5 mins, till it starts shooting up it is normal).
I am not able to establish connection with postgres from psql client.
In the log the following message keeps repeating:
WARNING:  worker took too long to start; canceled.

I tried commenting out various areas of my code, adding sleeps at different places of the core processing loop and even disabling the trigger but the issue occurs.

**Softwares and libraries used:**
go version go1.17.5 linux/amd64
Postgres 13.6, in Ubuntu
LibPq: https://github.com/lib/pq,

My core processing loop looks like this:

````
maxReconn := time.Minute
listener := pq.NewListener(<connectionstring>, minReconn, maxReconn, EventCallBackFn); // libpq used here.
defer listener.UnlistenAll();
if err = listener.Listen("mystream"); err != nil {
    panic(err);
}

var itemsProcessedSinceLastSleep int = 0;
for {
    select {
        case signal := <-signalChan:
            PgLog(PG_LOG, "Exiting loop due to termination signal : %d", signal);
            return 1;
        case pgstatus := <-pmStatusChan:
            PgLog(PG_LOG, "Exiting loop as postmaster is not running : %d ", pgstatus);
            return 1;
        case data := <-listener.Notify:
            itemsProcessedSinceLastSleep = itemsProcessedSinceLastSleep + 1;
            if itemsProcessedSinceLastSleep >= 1000 {
                time.Sleep(time.Millisecond * 10);
                itemsProcessedSinceLastSleep = 0;
            }
            ProcessChangeReceivedAtStream(data); // This performs the data processing
        case <-time.After(10 * time.Second):
            time.Sleep(100 * time.Millisecond);
            var cEpoch = time.Now().Unix();
            if cEpoch - lastConnChkTime > 1800 {
                lastConnChkTime = cEpoch;
                if err := listener.Ping(); err!=nil {
                    PgLog(PG_LOG, "Seems to be a problem with connection")
                }
            }
        default:
            time.Sleep(time.Millisecond * 100);
    }
}```
````